# What type of content is allowed to be used as arguments for C preprocessor macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Honestly I know the syntax of the C programming language well, but know almost nothing about the syntax of the C preprocessor, although I use it in my programming practice sometimes.

So the question. Suppose we have a simple macro that expands to nothing:

```
#define macro(param)
```

What is the restrictions for the syntax that can be put inside macro invoking construction?

It is certainly impossible to use single or multiple comma when invoking the macro:

```
macro(,); // won't compile
```

However if we put the comma into the brackets it will be accepted by C preprocessor:

```
macro((,)); // compiles fine
```

Of course, you can't use the comment characters:

```
macro(//); // compile error
```

because, as far as I know, comments are processed by preprocessor itself.

Unclosed quotes and round brackets aren't allowed too when using the macro:

```
macro("); // compile error
```

But characters unused in the C syntax are accepted well:

```
macro(@#$); // compiles
```

Even characters of foreign languages work fine:

```
macro(бла-бла-бла я пишу по-русски); // compiles too
```

Can I use a random valid C/C++ code in curly brackets when invoking the macro? Can I use a random valid C/C++ code without curly brackets? The following code seems to compile fine:

```
macro(int a = 5; printf("%d\n", a););
```

Comment: You need to read the standard document, there it will be explained in detail. If you just want to learn, if you are trying to abuse the preprocessor then take this advice: DON'T!. Note that for instance, spanning multiple lines of code with the preprocessor makes debugging very difficult, because it expands the whole block of code to a single line. so the debugger will report any error within the same line into the block of code which can be multiple lines (*logical lines*, *visual lines*, *segments separated by semicolon*).

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: The C preprocessor is not covered by the C standard.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Really? Let me make sure.

Comment: @anton_rh: This question is too broad. You seem to be looking for a tutorial on the C preprocessor.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield You are wrong, C standard covers macros.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield [Please take a look here](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10).

Comment: Please [read this link](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10), there you will see the syntax rules (*grammar*) of the preprocessor directives. Note: this is a [tag:c] resource, perhaps there are differences for c++, most c++ programmers NEVER use the preprocessor for writing macros so it's unlikely that you should. But if you're interested, I recommend searching for the appropriate resource. Bear in mind that c != c++ ... oops, undefined behavior

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Mea culpa; That's what I get for skimming too fast.

Comment: By the way "*logical lines, visual lines, segments separated by semicolon*" -> **statements**, it's just that the word eluded me

Comment: just remember that a 'macro' is NOTHING but some replacement text to be inserted into your source code wherever the macro is invoked

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass arbitrary text to be ignored with your proposed scheme:

- The C preprocessor will read the input file and parse it as a sequence of preprocessing tokens, after stripping comments, to pass to the macro as arguments. It matches parentheses to determine what tokens constitute arguments separated by `,`.
- Text containing strings or character constants with unrecognized escape sequences or stand alone backslashes does not parse as standard preprocessing token. Whether `macro(@#$);` compiles is implementation dependent.
- Note however that you can work around the `,` problem by defining your macro as taking a variable number of arguments:

  ```
  #define macro(...)
  ```

Comment: And comments are removed (treated as spaces) before the preprocessor gets to work.